# debugger for C/C++ and Java

Tags: java, c++, c

I mainly use vim, but I really like the debuggers used in modern IDEs such as Netbeans, Visual C++, and Eclipse and I am wondering if there were any debuggers like those except in a standalone program? I tried using gdb, but it seems that debugging will take a lot longer using a command line. I also tried ddd, but it was a little frustrating to use since it would not display some complex structures with arrays. I really like how the debuggers in the modern IDEs allow me to just click on the down arrow to view what are in my arrays something which I do not know how to do in gdb or ddd.

Comment: Why don't use use the modern debuggers in the IDEs if you like them.  Nothing is forcing you to give up vim, you can just use them for debugging if that is all you want them for. I was very reluctant to give up vim 10 years ago for an IDE, but I can't imagine going back now. The free version of IntelliJ is my favourite for Java. Netbeans is my favourite for C++ support.

Comment: I like the features of vim and I do not want to just create a project just to debug my program

Comment: AFAIK, Eclipse can import a project from an existing makefile or Ant script. So it should be no big effort to use Eclipse for debugging and stick to Vim for editing (like I do).

Comment: I use [viemu](http://www.viemu.com/) inside Visual Studio when on Windows works great.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if one of these worked out for you!

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at:

http://code.google.com/p/jswat/

It's a standalone java debugger. I'm afraid it doesn't support C++ debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Try Nemiver, which is a standalone graphical debugger for C and C++. It is openly developed as part of the GNOME project and uses gdb underneath.

http://projects.gnome.org/nemiver/

Comment: This one really looks promising. I'll give this one a try for C/C++ coding. Thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

For windows you can use [windbg](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx).  It is very good.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about Java, but for C++ you don't need an IDE to use a debugger. It is perfectly possible to code with vim and use a standalone debugger, such as windbg or gdb. In fact, that's what I do all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Use Eclipse.  You can easily create an Eclipse project around existing code, and still use VIM to edit your files while using Eclipse to debug.

Comment: Or use eclim - run both at the same time with the same files, so you can edit in vim, and switch to eclipse - already running, file already open and up to date - and debug.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ is free now so it should be a good choice, I've found it to be easier to use than Eclipse but I haven't used Eclipse too much. A few features like smart complete (Ctrl+Shift+Space that lets you import/complete constructors), independent run/debug consoles that can be viewed at the same time, hotswap debugging and autosave help me save time on day-to-day programming tasks. However, there's a lot of support and plug-ins for Eclipse since it's always been open source so it really depends on what you want to do.